# webView.loadUrl not working when i use loadDataWithBaseURL

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm using loadDataWithBaseURL for loading my local page from my assets, and after that, I need to call JavaScript functions from android, and I use webView.loadUrl() to run those functions as below, but nothing happens.

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:androidDataReciver('{\"order\":\"control_avatar_by_gps\"});
```

when I load my local page with webView.loadUrl all things are good, but I need to load my page with loadDataWithBaseURL and after that loadUrl for calling javascript functions are not working. 
where am i wrong? 
thank you.

Comment: the code you provided has a syntax issue. I think it should be
`webView.loadUrl("javascript:androidDataReciver({\"order\":\"control_avatar_by_gps\"})");`

Comment: in javascript side, i check, if receive string, it convert it to object, this is not my problem, because when i don't use loadDataWithBaseURL, it work.